# Compare a string that was read from a config ini file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, ini

I have a config.ini file like this:

```
[LABEL]
NAME = "eventName"
```

And I am reading it into my python code as shown below. However, when I compare it with the exactly the same string, the result is `False`. I wonder if I should use a different way to read this or I need to do something else?

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
my_label_name = config['LABEL']['name']

print("My label is: ", my_label_name, " and has type of: ", type(my_label_name))
My label is:  "eventName"  and has type of:  <class 'str'>

print(my_label_name == "eventName")
False
```

Comment: The values should no be enclosed in quotes, neither for ini files nor for configparser.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the config parser reads the content from your config file as string. In the config file, single and double quotes are not required to represent a string. The quotes will be considered as a separate character itself.

In your program, if you observe properly, you can see the value is getting printed with the quotes. So ***eventName*** and ***"eventName"*** are not the same. This is the reason you are getting ***False*** as the result. The screenshot of your program is given below.

[image]

So the solution is remove double quotes from your config file or remove double quotes at the time of reading the value.

The updated config file is given below.

```
[LABEL]
NAME = eventName
```

If you cannot remove double quotes from the config file, you need to handle it in the program. The sample code snippet is given below.

```
import ast
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

# Modify here
#my_label_name = config['LABEL']['name']
my_label_name = ast.literal_eval(config['LABEL']['name'])

print("My label is: ", my_label_name, " and has type of: ", type(my_label_name))

print(my_label_name == "eventName")
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `config['LABEL']['name']` is a str containing `"eventName"` with the double quotes.

Single (`'`) and double (`"`) quotes are unnecessary in INI where everything is a string.

Demo:

```py
from io import StringIO
import configparser

raw_config = """\
[LABEL]
NAME = "eventName"
"""

with StringIO(raw_config) as buf:
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read_file(buf)

print(config["LABEL"]["NAME"])  # "eventName"
```